# How to pass parameter as hash in Rails api with GET?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to pass params as a hash in url with postman like this

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/bill?album=3&song=4&song=7&album=6
```

I use this code to get param

```
 def param_hash
    params.permit(:album, :song)
  end
```

and print this value `param_hash.to_h`

This is a value i want **{"album"=3, "song"=>4, "album"=>6, "song"=>7}**
But in reality that's what i got **{"album"=>6, "song"=>7}** , just have only 1 hash in last.

Is there anyway to take all hash value in url?

Comment: You cannot have 2 keys with the same name and 2 values. You'll only get the last values. that's what you got.

Comment: "This is a value i want {"album"=3, "song"=>4, "album"=>6, "song"=>7}" - this hash is impossible. When doing `params_hash["song"]`,  would you expect to get back 4 or 7, and why?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The flow of this question is FE developer will send a hash value with key is (album or song) and the value is id (1,2,3,...), and i don't know the syntax FE team will send this hash in url and how i can take this hash in rails. So i think maybe my question is hard to understand :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
def param_hash
  params.permit(album: [], song: [])
end
```

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/bill?album[]=3&song[]=4&song[]=7&album[]=6
```

According to https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

> The permitted scalar types are String, Symbol, NilClass, Numeric, TrueClass, FalseClass, Date, Time, DateTime, StringIO, IO, ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile and Rack::Test::UploadedFile.
>
> To declare that the value in params must be an array of permitted scalar values map the key to an empty array:
>
> params.permit(:id => [])

Comment: I think, in addition to this, the data also needs to be sent as `?song[]=4&song[]=7&...`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ah yes thank you. Made the edit to reflect your input.

Comment: @DennyMueller Tks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/bill?data={album: 3,song: 4,song: 7,album: 6 }
```

Use the above logic and permit the 'data' object.